# Correctly passing Value back and forth to/from a Blazor child component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Ok, so for a child component in Blazor server, if the Value passed to it is a primitive (string, int, etc.) it's very simple to follow the contract of passed in to Value, passed back to ValueChanged. Because it's passed by value, making a change to Value in the child component is not seen in the parent.

But if you pass an object, now it can't be that easy, I think. Tell me if this is correct.

If it is passed as Value="address" then if I set Value.City = "Boulder"; that address.Name, in the parent component, will see the changed value. And that's breaking the contract which can cause problems. Correct?

And so, to handle this well I think requires the following:

1. I have an _address object in the child component.
2. In the child's SetParametersAsync() I have to watch for the parameter Value being passed in. When it is, I set _address= parameter.Value;.
3. I call ValueChanged when I see a change. The parent then should update Value to match. (And if it doesn't, that's on them.)

AddressForm.razor I can do binding - because it's to my internal `_value`, not to the public `Value`.

```
<DxTextBox @bind-Text="_value.StreetNumberAndName"
           ReadOnly="ReadOnly"
           ShowValidationIcon="true" />
```

Then in my code behind I do:

```
public AddressForm()
{
    // to avoid null pointer issues until SetParametersAsync is called
    Value = new AddressFormPageModel();
    _value = new AddressFormPageModel();

    // we start with it set to true until we get the first Value= set below.
    IsSelected = true;
}

public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
{
        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            if (parameter.Name != nameof(Value))
                continue;
            if (parameter.Value is not AddressFormPageModel newValue)
                continue;
            _value = new AddressFormPageModel(newValue);

            // we hit this code including the first time it processes Value= which
            // is the initialization. This determines if the address is initially
            // verified. 
            // And it first creates an empty Value, then sets the passed in one
            if (IsFirstSet && ((! string.IsNullOrEmpty(_value.StreetNumberAndName)) 
                               || (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(_value.City))))
            {
                IsSelected = Value.IsVerified;
                IsFirstSet = false;
            }
        }

        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
}
private async void OnFieldChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // we're tied to the EditContext of the parent component, so we need to make sure
    // this is for one of our fields
    if (e.FieldIdentifier.Model is not AddressFormPageModel)
        return;

    if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
        await ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_value);
}
```

And the finally, in the parent razor code:

```
private void OnAddressChanged(AddressFormPageModel address)
{
    HasUnsavedChanges = true;
    IsAddressVerified = false;
    // note in the razor it has Value="ProfilePageModel.AddressModel"
    ProfilePageModel.AddressModel = address;
}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record here's a simple Value Object implementation:

There's no longer any Parameter Value setting, a new `AddressValue` is returned each time in the `EventCallback`.

BUT, you can't do a simple bind to `AddressValueEditor` any more. Address is now a `AddressValue` : an immutable value object.  You need a custom setter.

```cs
public record AddressValue
{
    public string? City { get; init; }
    public string? Country { get; init; }
}
```

`AddressValueEditor`:

```cs
<div>
    <label class="form-label">City</label>
    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_city" @bind-Value:after="CityChanged" />
    <ValidationMessage For="() => Value.City" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="form-label">Country</label>
    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_country" @bind-Value:after="CountryChanged" />
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext editContext { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public AddressValue Value { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<AddressValue> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private ValidationMessageStore? _messageStore;
    private string? _city;
    private string? _country;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(editContext);
        _city = this.Value.City;
        _country = this.Value.Country;
        _messageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(editContext);
    }

    private async Task CityChanged()
    {
        var newAddress = this.Value with { City = _city };
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(newAddress);
    }

    private async Task CountryChanged()
    {
        var newAddress = this.Value with { Country = _country };
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(newAddress);
    }
}
```

And demo:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Test</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm Model="_person">

    <AddressValueEditor @bind-Value:get="_person.Address" @bind-Value:set="this.SetAddress" />

</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>City: @_person.Address.City</pre>
    <pre>Country: @_person.Address.Country</pre>
</div>
@code {
    private Person _person = new();

    private void SetAddress(AddressValue address)
    {
        _person.Address = address;   
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public AddressValue Address { get; set; } = new();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, follow up question. If this was a component released for general use, and therefore had to support any type of use including Value being assigned to an object (class, pass be reference), is my approach a good one? I ask because I want to know if I’m understanding this all correctly. TIA

Answer (score 1):

*(SEE FULL CODE EXAMPLE AT BOTTOM)*

The easiest way to pass complex(or any valuetypes) objects from a Child component to a Parent component, and changing its value and reflecting it back to the parent component, is by using CascadingValue (CascadingParameter) and EventCallback;

1. In **Parent**: Surround the child component with CascadingValue and the object 'myCascadedAddress' with a name:

```
<CascadingValue Value="@myCascadedAddress" Name="AKeyNameToCatchThisObject">
    <MyChildComponent OnAddressChanged="OnAddressChangedFromChild" />
</CascadingValue>
```

2. In **Parent**: Create a method that sets its value when the child changes it:

```
void OnAddressChangedFromChild(Address changedAddress) => myCascadedAddress = changedAddress;
```

3. In **Child**: Catch the cascaded value by using CascadingParameter:

```
[CascadingParameter(Name = "AKeyNameToCatchThisObject")] // remember Name from step 1, to set its value
Address CascadedAddressObject { get; set; } = null!;
```

4. In **Child**: Create the EventCallback property and make it a Parameter (see 1st step):

```
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<Address> OnAddressChanged { get; set; }
```

5. In **Child**: Change the address and send the value to the parent method 'OnAddressChangedFromChild':

```
async Task ChangeCityAsync()
{
    CascadedAddressObject.City = "Seattle"; // Changes the address object

    await OnAddressChanged.InvokeAsync(CascadedAddressObject); // Calls back to parent with new address object
}
```

**Full code example:**

MyParentComponent.razor:

```
@page "/"

<h1>Parent</h1>

<p>Parent: @myCascadedAddress?.City</p>

<CascadingValue Value="@myCascadedAddress" Name="AKeyNameToCatchThisObject">
    <MyChildComponent OnAddressChanged="OnAddressChangedFromChild" />
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    public sealed class Address { public string City { get; set; } = null!; }

    Address? myCascadedAddress;

    protected override void OnInitialized() => myCascadedAddress = new Address { City = "Redmond" };

    void OnAddressChangedFromChild(Address changedAddress) => myCascadedAddress = changedAddress;
}
```

MyChildComponent.razor:

```
@using static BlazorApp7.Pages.MyParentComponent; // cuz Address object defined in parent

<hr />

<h1>Child</h1>

<p>Child: @CascadedAddressObject.City</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ChangeCityAsync">Change City from Child</button>

<hr />

@code {
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "AKeyNameToCatchThisObject")] // Name from parent must match in order to set its value
    private Address CascadedAddressObject { get; set; } = null!;

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Address> OnAddressChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task ChangeCityAsync()
    {
        CascadedAddressObject.City = "Seattle"; // Changes the address object

        await OnAddressChanged.InvokeAsync(CascadedAddressObject); // Calls back to parent with new address object
    }
}
```

The alternative:

What you're doing - using SetParameters{Async}, which is good, if you want to catch the parameter value as soon as it becomes available and manipulating the value BEFORE it is being set - which is not always necessary, since you can use attributes/parameters (like my code above).

OnParametersSet{Async} will be called anytime a [CascadingParameter]/[Parameter] becomes available or changed, which you can make use of if you want, and is more commonly used than SetParameters{Async}.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. However, I'm not wild on that approach because I want to deliver a component that they can just add with no requirement to surround it with anything. Also, why would you use `OnParametersSetAsync` instead of `SetParametersAsync`?

Comment: Because OnParametersSet is an event that triggers everytime it is set or changes, so *after* it's set or changed - which is why it's mostly used. Compared to SetParametersAsync, which is only used *before* it is set to the given property.

Comment: See the below answer from MrC, it will be possible without surrounding it with CascadingValue by doing a @bind-Value="AddressObject".

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't given much context, I'm making some educated guesses based on previous questions.

Let's assume you have something like this.  Everything is a class, which I take from the question being about reference types.

```cs
public class Person {
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; } = new();
}
```

```cs
public class Address
{
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public string? Country { get; set; }
}
```

So if you have an edit control for Address you do something like this:

```cs
<EditForm Model="_person">
    <AddressEditor @bind-Value="_person.Address" />
</EditForm>

@code{
    private Person _person = new();
```

And in `AddressEditor` you have:

```cs
@code {
    [Parameter] public Address Value { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Address> ValueChanged { get; set; }
```

It's important to recognise that `Value` in the edit control and `_person` in the parent are all references to the same object.  Change the value of `City` in an input in `AddressEditor` you have changed the value of `_person.City`.  You won't see that in the UI until it renders, but it's there in the C# object.  So you don't actually need to pass the change back though the EventCallback for the parent [and the data pipeline to see it], and you don't need to jump through hoops to try to track changes in `AddressEditor`.

Here's an `AddressEditor` to demo one way of addressing the problem.  It uses internal fields for the individual input controls to bind to and the `bind:after` to update Value.  Note I'm doing what @HH and I say is a NONO in updating the [Parameter] because I think it's a valid to do so here.  It's a reference type not a value type.  There's no mismatch happening, everyone is referencing the same object.  One alternative approach is to build a new copy of `Address` each time, but that will probably cause issues in your complex model further back down your EF data pipeline. The other is to have bind values for each field, which is rather long winded.

```cs
@implements IDisposable

<div>
    <label class="form-label">City</label>
    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_city" @bind-Value:after="CityChanged" />
    <ValidationMessage For="() => Value.City" />
</div>
<div>
    <label class="form-label">Country</label>
    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_country" @bind-Value:after="CountryChanged" />
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private EditContext editContext { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public Address Value { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<Address> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private ValidationMessageStore? _messageStore;
    private string? _city;
    private string? _country;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(editContext);
        _messageStore = new ValidationMessageStore(editContext);
        editContext.OnValidationRequested += Validate;
    }

    private async Task CityChanged()
    {
        Value.City = _city;
        ValidateCity();
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.Value);
    }

    private async Task CountryChanged()
    {
        Value.Country = _country;
        await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.Value);
    }

    private void Validate( object? sender, ValidationRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateCity();
    }

    private void ValidateCity()
    {
        var fi = new FieldIdentifier(Value, "City");
        var messages = editContext.GetValidationMessages(fi);

        var wasValid = !messages.Any();
        var isValid = this.Value.City?.Length > 2;

        if (wasValid && !isValid)
        {
            _messageStore?.Add(fi, "City must have more than 2 characters");
            editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
        }

        if (!wasValid && isValid)
        {
            _messageStore?.Clear(fi);
            editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        editContext.OnValidationRequested -= Validate;
    }
}
```

and:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm Model="_person">
    
    <AddressEditor @bind-Value="_person.Address" />

</EditForm>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>City: @_person.Address.City</pre>
    <pre>Country: @_person.Address.Country</pre>
</div>
@code{
    private Person _person = new();

    public class Person {
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; } = new();
    }
}
```

Note that I would use a value object for address.  But that's another story.

#### A note on the "don't set a [Parameter] rule"

You don't set [Parameter] defined properties in a component because by doing so you create a conflict between the value in the component, the value held by the Renderer and the source value in the parent.

However, when dealing with reference objects, such as a POCO, there are no longer three values, just three references to the same object.  Change one and you change all.  Returning the reference in an EventCallback does nothing.

With reference objects, there's no longer a conflict.  All rules are made to be broken, you just need to understand when you can and can't do so.

Comment: I may not have fully answered your question here, but hopefully you are little more enlightened, and my example demonstrates one or more ways to go forward.

Comment: Ok, so you and @HH got me to understand why I should not assign to a Parameter in the child component. And I then implemented it to not do so. And then here you say it's ok to do so.   
  
Doesn't setting the parameter leave open the problem with the MudBlazor rating control? Isn't it safer/cleaner to send it back up with ValueChanged and allow the parent razor file to decide if that change will be set in the Value object?

Comment: Also, if it is a value object, then I can use the value that's passed down because changes I make won't be seen by the parent. Unfortunately, as the child component I can't force the parent to only use a value object.

Comment: So a follow up question. Is there any downside to the approach I implemented? Because I prefer to not directly write to the parameter. And if so, any big issues on using  OnParametersSetAsync vs. SetParametersAsync?

Comment: Hands up, guilty, yes true on not setting Parameters. I say it's OK here because [I think] we're dealing with a reference object, not a value object.  HH may shoot me down in flames for even suggesting it.

Comment: For reference is `AddressFormPageModel` really a value object?

Comment: Looking at your code I realise I've missed this line ` _value = new AddressFormPageModel(newValue);`  I had thought you were just passing the same object back all the time, which is why I said set the Parameter.
`

Comment: Nope, AddressFormPageModel is a class, not a struct. It's very rare I make something a struct which is a habit from my C++ days (decades ago).

Comment: See my update above on setting Parameter.  I mostly use records today, I'm a convert to the read only data pipeline and implementing the flux pattern to control object mutation.

Comment: Part of this is my last 20 years. I built a company where we sold a library and as such, we had to have that API handle being called a million different ways. When I create components I retain that mindset even though these components are for my own use only. So I could require that you assign a record, not a class, to Value. Something I'll have to consider on the next version.